# How can I change this code for multiplication?

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I'm using for addition of inputs. How can I change this code for multiplication?

```
function sumIt() {
  var total = 0, val;
  $('.inst_amount').each(function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    val = isNaN(val) || $.trim(val) === "" ? 0 : parseFloat(val);
    total += val;
  });
  $('#total_price').html(Math.round(total));
  $('#total_amount').val(Math.round(total));
}

$(function() {

  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    $("#container input").last()
      .before($("<input />").prop("class","inst_amount").val(0))
      .before("<br/>");
    sumIt();  
  });

  $(document).on('input', '.inst_amount', sumIt);
  sumIt() // run when loading
});
```

Comment: You want to multiply instead of add?  Change `+` to `*`?

Comment: Simply change the line `total += val;` to `total *= val;`?

Comment: i tried but i doesnt work

Comment: @FrizbiSosyal Can you provide a working example for the sum operation?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kmL9ef0w/ this is a working example  @silentw

Comment: Be more descriptive than "it doesn't work".  Wrong result?  Getting an error?  What is it doing and what are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `var total = 1;`

Use `total *= parseFloat(Val);`// for multiply
Or use `total = total * parseFloat(Val);`

Comment: i want to multiply instead of add

Comment: Your initial value of total is in 0. This is always give you the zero . So initialize the total as 1. And change the symbol to * instead of +